# In Rails 4, how do I configure a list of trusted proxies for RemoteIp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ip-address

My application logs the ip address of each user that logs in, but I've noticed that it's logging the IP address of our load balancer instead of the actual client ip. Researching the issue, I believe it's because our load balancers use publically routable ip addresses, and Rails is ignoring the X-Forwarded-For header assuming it's been spoofed. The solution appears to be to 'whitelist' the range of ip's used by our load balancers.

My question is, exactly how do I do that, for rails 4.1.x? Here's what I have now in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.custom_proxies = %r{
  ^100\.30 | # production environment load balancers
  ^200\.40 | # dev environment load balancers
}x
```

I tried to format it like the TRUSTED_PROXIES in remote_ip.rb, but maybe it should be a string or an array, or a differently formatted regex? Any help on the details are much appreciated. Bonus upvote if you can suggest an integration test that would catch this configuration breaking in a future version of rails. :-)

*UPDATE*

I've tried multiple ways to update this, and had slightly more success using `config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies`. This keeps my load balancers from getting logged, but leaves all IP addresses logged as '127.0.0.1', whether they're internal or external. In logs/unicorn.log, the ip addresses are coming in as [external address, 10.* address, load balancer address], so I know the problem is at the rack or rails layer, not earlier in apache or nginx. I've also tried to replace the TRUSTED_PROXIES constant with a list that does NOT include the 10.* range (because internal users have that range), but to no apparent effect.

At this point, it looks like Rails 4.1.x is broken for any application that has real users coming from non-public IP addresses, or any application hosted in a network environment that has a load balancer with an external IP address.

Answer (score 7):

As of Rails 4.2 you have to define the proxies in a different way:

```
config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies = %w(100.30.0.0/16 200.40.0.0/16).
  map { |proxy| IPAddr.new(proxy) }
```

See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5223#issuecomment-199082324

Answer (score 0):

You can add another configutation option `config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check` so Rails doesn't check for IP spoofing.

The option is described on the rails guide about [configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware) and on the [ActionDispatch::RemoteIp module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/RemoteIp.html)

Comment: I corrected my configuration from `config.action_dispatch.check_ip_spoofing = false` to `config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check = false`, and included my internal load balancer ip's in the `config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies` option, but it still doesn't solve the problem for me. Just setting the ip_spoofing_check changes nothing. Setting the trusted_proxies setting changes nothing. Doing those things plus monkey-patching ActionDispatch::Request::trusted_proxy? to look at the configured trusted_proxies causes it to log all requests as 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I've configured a test application with Rails 3.2.17 (Apache + Passenger) behind a proxy (Apache) and everything works out of the box, without adding any configuration to action_dispatch

Comment: Found an interesting post about the x-forwarded-for header: http://blog.gingerlime.com/2012/rails-ip-spoofing-vulnerabilities-and-protection/

Comment: That post is a good read. Also read the comments on this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5223. It appears that for some of us, this has worked off and on in different versions of rails, and seems broken at the moment.

Comment: Although this didn't fully answer my question, I appreciate the time you took to look into it and test. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!! It's a pitty we didn't solved the issue completly. At least I understand better how x-forwarded-for should be used